# Datatables, how can I get the attribute of an element on hover using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the attribute data on hover of a `div` inside a `td` element when the user is hovering a `tr` element like I tried below:

```js
(function(window, document, undefined) {

  var factory = function($, DataTable) {
    "use strict";

    $('.search-toggle').click(function() {
      if ($('.hiddensearch').css('display') == 'none')
        $('.hiddensearch').slideDown();
      else
        $('.hiddensearch').slideUp();
    });

    /* Set the defaults for DataTables initialisation */
    $.extend(true, DataTable.defaults, {
      dom: "<'hiddensearch'f'>" +
        "tr" +
        "<'table-footer'lip'>",
      renderer: 'material'
    });

    /* Default class modification */
    $.extend(DataTable.ext.classes, {
      sWrapper: "dataTables_wrapper",
      sFilterInput: "form-control input-sm",
      sLengthSelect: "form-control input-sm"
    });

    /* Bootstrap paging button renderer */
    DataTable.ext.renderer.pageButton.material = function(settings, host, idx, buttons, page, pages) {
      var api = new DataTable.Api(settings);
      var classes = settings.oClasses;
      var lang = settings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
      var btnDisplay, btnClass, counter = 0;

      var attach = function(container, buttons) {
        var i, ien, node, button;
        var clickHandler = function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (!$(e.currentTarget).hasClass('disabled')) {
            api.page(e.data.action).draw(false);
          }
        };

        for (i = 0, ien = buttons.length; i < ien; i++) {
          button = buttons[i];

          if ($.isArray(button)) {
            attach(container, button);
          } else {
            btnDisplay = '';
            btnClass = '';

            switch (button) {

              case 'first':
                btnDisplay = lang.sFirst;
                btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
                  '' : ' disabled');
                break;

              case 'previous':
                btnDisplay = '<i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>';
                btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
                  '' : ' disabled');
                break;

              case 'next':
                btnDisplay = '<i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>';
                btnClass = button + (page < pages - 1 ?
                  '' : ' disabled');
                break;

              case 'last':
                btnDisplay = lang.sLast;
                btnClass = button + (page < pages - 1 ?
                  '' : ' disabled');
                break;

            }

            if (btnDisplay) {
              node = $('<li>', {
                  'class': classes.sPageButton + ' ' + btnClass,
                  'id': idx === 0 && typeof button === 'string' ?
                    settings.sTableId + '_' + button : null
                })
                .append($('<a>', {
                    'href': '#',
                    'aria-controls': settings.sTableId,
                    'data-dt-idx': counter,
                    'tabindex': settings.iTabIndex
                  })
                  .html(btnDisplay)
                )
                .appendTo(container);

              settings.oApi._fnBindAction(
                node, {
                  action: button
                }, clickHandler
              );

              counter++;
            }
          }
        }
      };

      // IE9 throws an 'unknown error' if document.activeElement is used
      // inside an iframe or frame. 
      var activeEl;

      try {
        // Because this approach is destroying and recreating the paging
        // elements, focus is lost on the select button which is bad for
        // accessibility. So we want to restore focus once the draw has
        // completed
        activeEl = $(document.activeElement).data('dt-idx');
      } catch (e) {}

      attach(
        $(host).empty().html('<ul class="material-pagination"/>').children('ul'),
        buttons
      );

      if (activeEl) {
        $(host).find('[data-dt-idx=' + activeEl + ']').focus();
      }
    };

    /*
     * TableTools Bootstrap compatibility
     * Required TableTools 2.1+
     */
    if (DataTable.TableTools) {
      // Set the classes that TableTools uses to something suitable for Bootstrap
      $.extend(true, DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
        "container": "DTTT btn-group",
        "buttons": {
          "normal": "btn btn-default",
          "disabled": "disabled"
        },
        "collection": {
          "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
          "buttons": {
            "normal": "",
            "disabled": "disabled"
          }
        },
        "print": {
          "info": "DTTT_print_info"
        },
        "select": {
          "row": "active"
        }
      });

      // Have the collection use a material compatible drop down
      $.extend(true, DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
        "collection": {
          "container": "ul",
          "button": "li",
          "liner": "a"
        }
      });
    }

  }; // /factory

  // Define as an AMD module if possible
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery', 'datatables'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery'), require('datatables'));
  } else if (jQuery) {
    // Otherwise simply initialise as normal, stopping multiple evaluation
    factory(jQuery, jQuery.fn.dataTable);
  }

})(window, document);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datatable').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sStripClasses": "",
      "sSearch": "",
      "sSearchPlaceholder": "Enter Keywords Here",
      "sInfo": "_START_ -_END_ of _TOTAL_",
      "sLengthMenu": '<span>Rows per page:</span><select class="browser-default">' +
        '<option value="10">10</option>' +
        '<option value="20">20</option>' +
        '<option value="30">30</option>' +
        '<option value="40">40</option>' +
        '<option value="50">50</option>' +
        '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
        '</select></div>'
    },
    bAutoWidth: false
  });
});

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log('id: '+id);
    }
}, ".wrap-main table tbody tr td");
```

```css
div.material-table {
  padding: 0;
}

div.material-table .hiddensearch {
  padding: 0 14px 0 24px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
  display: none;
}

div.material-table .hiddensearch input {
  margin: 0;
  border: transparent 0 !important;
  height: 48px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .84);
}

div.material-table .hiddensearch input:active {
  border: transparent 0 !important;
}

div.material-table table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

div.material-table .table-header {
  height: 64px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
}

div.material-table .table-header .actions {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

div.material-table .table-header .btn-flat {
    min-width: 36px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}

div.material-table .table-header input {
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
}

div.material-table .table-header i {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-size: 24px;
}

div.material-table .table-footer {
  height: 56px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

div.material-table .table-footer .dataTables_length {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

div.material-table .table-footer label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row
  /* works with row or column */
  
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .select-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row
  /* works with row or column */
  
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .dataTables_info,
div.material-table .table-footer .dataTables_length {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .material-pagination {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .material-pagination li:first-child {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .material-pagination li a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

div.material-table .table-footer .select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}

div.material-table .table-footer select {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

div.material-table .table-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

div.material-table table tr td {
  padding: 0 0 0 56px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

div.material-table table tr td a {
  color: inherit;
}

div.material-table table tr td a i {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

div.material-table table tr {
  font-size: 12px;
}

div.material-table table th {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #757575;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  height: 56px;
  padding-left: 56px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: none !important;
}

div.material-table table th.sorting_asc,
div.material-table table th.sorting_desc {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}

div.material-table table th.sorting:after,
div.material-table table th.sorting_asc:after,
div.material-table table th.sorting_desc:after {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: normal;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: "arrow_back";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.material-table table th.sorting:hover:after,
div.material-table table th.sorting_asc:after,
div.material-table table th.sorting_desc:after {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.material-table table th.sorting_desc:after {
  content: "arrow_forward";
}

div.material-table table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

div.material-table table th:first-child,
div.material-table table td:first-child {
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
}

div.material-table table th:last-child,
div.material-table table td:last-child {
  padding: 0 14px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div id="admin" class="col s12">
    <div class="card material-table">
      <div class="table-header">
        <span class="table-title">Material Datatable</span>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#add_users" class="modal-trigger waves-effect btn-flat nopadding"><i class="material-icons">person_add</i></a>
          <a href="#" class="search-toggle waves-effect btn-flat nopadding"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-main">
        <table id="datatable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Airi Satou<div data-id="8" class="worker"></div></td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>33</td>
              <td>2008/11/28</td>
              <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Brielle Williamson<div data-id="8" class="worker"></div></td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2012/12/02</td>
              <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Herrod Chandler<div data-id="8" class="worker"></div></td>
              <td>Sales Assistant</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>59</td>
              <td>2012/08/06</td>
              <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Rhona Davidson<div data-id="8" class="worker"></div></td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>2010/10/14</td>
              <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried also using this:

```
$( ".wrap-main table tbody td" ).mouseover(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log('id: '+id);
});
```

My variable `id` is "undefined" but why?

Comment: because the cell doesnt have a `track-id` some div's inside cells have a `data-id` plus your selector doesn't only select the cells with `data-id` but every cell in that table.

Comment: @Steve my mistake...it's not that the problem

Comment: need to use `$(this).find('div').attr('data-id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. You're looking on the `td`, not the `div`. You can find the `div` by using `$(this).find("[data-id]")`.
2. <s>You're looking for `data-track-id`, but there's only `data-id`</s> *Turns out that was just an editing issue in the question.*

Fix those...

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      var id = $(this).find('[data-id]').attr('data-id');
      // -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      console.log('id: '+id);
    }
}, ".wrap-main table tbody tr td");
```

...and it works:

```js
(function(window, document, undefined) {

  var factory = function($, DataTable) {
    "use strict";

    $('.search-toggle').click(function() {
      if ($('.hiddensearch').css('display') == 'none')
        $('.hiddensearch').slideDown();
      else
        $('.hiddensearch').slideUp();
    });

    /* Set the defaults for DataTables initialisation */
    $.extend(true, DataTable.defaults, {
      dom: "<'hiddensearch'f'>" +
        "tr" +
        "<'table-footer'lip'>",
      renderer: 'material'
    });

    /* Default class modification */
    $.extend(DataTable.ext.classes, {
      sWrapper: "dataTables_wrapper",
      sFilterInput: "form-control input-sm",
      sLengthSelect: "form-control input-sm"
    });

    /* Bootstrap paging button renderer */
    DataTable.ext.renderer.pageButton.material = function(settings, host, idx, buttons, page, pages) {
      var api = new DataTable.Api(settings);
      var classes = settings.oClasses;
      var lang = settings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
      var btnDisplay, btnClass, counter = 0;

      var attach = function(container, buttons) {
        var i, ien, node, button;
        var clickHandler = function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (!$(e.currentTarget).hasClass('disabled')) {
            api.page(e.data.action).draw(false);
          }
        };

        for (i = 0, ien = buttons.length; i < ien; i++) {
          button = buttons[i];

          if ($.isArray(button)) {
            attach(container, button);
          } else {
            btnDisplay = '';
            btnClass = '';

            switch (button) {

              case 'first':
                btnDisplay = lang.sFirst;
                btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
                  '' : ' disabled');
                break;

              case 'previous':
                btnDisplay = '<i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>';
                btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
                  '' : ' disabled');
                break;

              case 'next':
                btnDisplay = '<i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>';
                btnClass = button + (page < pages - 1 ?
                  '' : ' disabled');
                break;

              case 'last':
                btnDisplay = lang.sLast;
                btnClass = button + (page < pages - 1 ?
                  '' : ' disabled');
                break;

            }

            if (btnDisplay) {
              node = $('<li>', {
                  'class': classes.sPageButton + ' ' + btnClass,
                  'id': idx === 0 && typeof button === 'string' ?
                    settings.sTableId + '_' + button : null
                })
                .append($('<a>', {
                    'href': '#',
                    'aria-controls': settings.sTableId,
                    'data-dt-idx': counter,
                    'tabindex': settings.iTabIndex
                  })
                  .html(btnDisplay)
                )
                .appendTo(container);

              settings.oApi._fnBindAction(
                node, {
                  action: button
                }, clickHandler
              );

              counter++;
            }
          }
        }
      };

      // IE9 throws an 'unknown error' if document.activeElement is used
      // inside an iframe or frame. 
      var activeEl;

      try {
        // Because this approach is destroying and recreating the paging
        // elements, focus is lost on the select button which is bad for
        // accessibility. So we want to restore focus once the draw has
        // completed
        activeEl = $(document.activeElement).data('dt-idx');
      } catch (e) {}

      attach(
        $(host).empty().html('<ul class="material-pagination"/>').children('ul'),
        buttons
      );

      if (activeEl) {
        $(host).find('[data-dt-idx=' + activeEl + ']').focus();
      }
    };

    /*
     * TableTools Bootstrap compatibility
     * Required TableTools 2.1+
     */
    if (DataTable.TableTools) {
      // Set the classes that TableTools uses to something suitable for Bootstrap
      $.extend(true, DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
        "container": "DTTT btn-group",
        "buttons": {
          "normal": "btn btn-default",
          "disabled": "disabled"
        },
        "collection": {
          "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
          "buttons": {
            "normal": "",
            "disabled": "disabled"
          }
        },
        "print": {
          "info": "DTTT_print_info"
        },
        "select": {
          "row": "active"
        }
      });

      // Have the collection use a material compatible drop down
      $.extend(true, DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
        "collection": {
          "container": "ul",
          "button": "li",
          "liner": "a"
        }
      });
    }

  }; // /factory

  // Define as an AMD module if possible
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery', 'datatables'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery'), require('datatables'));
  } else if (jQuery) {
    // Otherwise simply initialise as normal, stopping multiple evaluation
    factory(jQuery, jQuery.fn.dataTable);
  }

})(window, document);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datatable').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sStripClasses": "",
      "sSearch": "",
      "sSearchPlaceholder": "Enter Keywords Here",
      "sInfo": "_START_ -_END_ of _TOTAL_",
      "sLengthMenu": '<span>Rows per page:</span><select class="browser-default">' +
        '<option value="10">10</option>' +
        '<option value="20">20</option>' +
        '<option value="30">30</option>' +
        '<option value="40">40</option>' +
        '<option value="50">50</option>' +
        '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
        '</select></div>'
    },
    bAutoWidth: false
  });
});

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      var id = $(this).find('[data-id]').attr('data-id');
        console.log('id: '+id);
    }
}, ".wrap-main table tbody tr td");
```

```css
div.material-table {
  padding: 0;
}

div.material-table .hiddensearch {
  padding: 0 14px 0 24px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
  display: none;
}

div.material-table .hiddensearch input {
  margin: 0;
  border: transparent 0 !important;
  height: 48px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .84);
}

div.material-table .hiddensearch input:active {
  border: transparent 0 !important;
}

div.material-table table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

div.material-table .table-header {
  height: 64px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
}

div.material-table .table-header .actions {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

div.material-table .table-header .btn-flat {
    min-width: 36px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}

div.material-table .table-header input {
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
}

div.material-table .table-header i {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-size: 24px;
}

div.material-table .table-footer {
  height: 56px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

div.material-table .table-footer .dataTables_length {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

div.material-table .table-footer label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row
  /* works with row or column */
  
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .select-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row
  /* works with row or column */
  
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .dataTables_info,
div.material-table .table-footer .dataTables_length {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .material-pagination {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .material-pagination li:first-child {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

div.material-table .table-footer .material-pagination li a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

div.material-table .table-footer .select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}

div.material-table .table-footer select {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

div.material-table .table-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

div.material-table table tr td {
  padding: 0 0 0 56px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

div.material-table table tr td a {
  color: inherit;
}

div.material-table table tr td a i {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

div.material-table table tr {
  font-size: 12px;
}

div.material-table table th {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #757575;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  height: 56px;
  padding-left: 56px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: none !important;
}

div.material-table table th.sorting_asc,
div.material-table table th.sorting_desc {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}

div.material-table table th.sorting:after,
div.material-table table th.sorting_asc:after,
div.material-table table th.sorting_desc:after {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: normal;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: "arrow_back";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.material-table table th.sorting:hover:after,
div.material-table table th.sorting_asc:after,
div.material-table table th.sorting_desc:after {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.material-table table th.sorting_desc:after {
  content: "arrow_forward";
}

div.material-table table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

div.material-table table th:first-child,
div.material-table table td:first-child {
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
}

div.material-table table th:last-child,
div.material-table table td:last-child {
  padding: 0 14px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div id="admin" class="col s12">
    <div class="card material-table">
      <div class="table-header">
        <span class="table-title">Material Datatable</span>
        <div class="actions">
          <a href="#add_users" class="modal-trigger waves-effect btn-flat nopadding"><i class="material-icons">person_add</i></a>
          <a href="#" class="search-toggle waves-effect btn-flat nopadding"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-main">
        <table id="datatable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Airi Satou<div data-id="8" class="worker"></div></td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>33</td>
              <td>2008/11/28</td>
              <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Brielle Williamson<div data-id="8" class="worker"></div></td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2012/12/02</td>
              <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Herrod Chandler<div data-id="8" class="worker"></div></td>
              <td>Sales Assistant</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>59</td>
              <td>2012/08/06</td>
              <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Rhona Davidson<div data-id="8" class="worker"></div></td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>2010/10/14</td>
              <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I used `attr`, not `data`. `data` is *not* an accessor for `data-*` attributes; it's both less than that (never *writes* to `data-*` attributes), and more than that (maintains a data cache separate from the element). Unless you need `data`'s specific features, it's best to stick with `attr`. But `data('id')` would have worked, provided nothing updates the attribute later (if it did, the values would get out of sync).

Comment: Yes, thanks I forgot to remove "track" for this example

Comment: @NineCattoRules: Ah... :-)